# SecureSocial redirects all to onLoginGoTo - Play 2.1

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, securesocial

I added securesocial to a Play 2.1.3 project (Scala), it works fine with deadbolt.

I expect non-authenticated requests to be redirected to login page and after log-in back to the original URL they had requested. However, in this case after login they are always being sent to the path defined at onLoginGoToin securesocial.conf, regardless of the page they requested before login.

Am I missing some configurations?

Thanks,

**EDIT:** 
Here's how I'm using securesocial with deadbolt in my actions:

```
def list = Pattern("products.list", PatternType.EQUALITY, new MyDeadboltHandler) {
  SecuredAction { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.products.list(Product.listAll))
  }
}
```

And onAuthFailure in myDeadboltHandler:

```
def onAuthFailure[A](request: Request[A]): Result = {
  Logger.debug("authentication failure")
  Results.Redirect(securesocial.controllers.routes.LoginPage.login())
}
```

**EDIT2:**

```
implicit def username(implicit request: RequestHeader):Option[Identity] = SecureSocial.currentUser
override def getSubject[A](request: Request[A]): Option[Subject] = {
    val maySession = username(request)
    maySession match {
       case Some(session) => Some(new User(session.identityId.userId))
       case _ => None
    }
  }
```

Comment: Not sure how you are using it with Deadbolt. Have you seen the sample app? It is supposed to be working that way.

Comment: @Jorge. Thanks for your comment and for such an amazing plugin. I edited my question with more details. I think original url should be stored in a cookie but I do not see any cookie except id.

Comment: What does MyDeadboltHandler do if the user is not authenticated? It could be that you are not getting to execute the SecuredAction implementation.  It's there where SecureSocial saves the url the user was trying to access.

Comment: @Jorge: I edited the question. In case there is no user, it returns a "None" to tell Deadbolt that there's no valid user.